# z-index'ed parent div background not showing

Tags: css

I have a bootstrap jumbotron with a video background. The video background is position absolute and z-index: -1 and the jumbotron div is position relative and z-index: 1. The desired result here is to have a white transparent overlay on top of the video. However the background property is not visible, even when i switch it to say a solid color. here is a pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLEOoO?editors=1100

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="block-1" class="block row jumbotron">
    <div class="col col-md-12">
      <respond-html id="html-5" description="HTML">                  
        <video class="video-background" autoplay="" loop="" poster="/static/template/themes/video-theme/video/video.jpg">
          <source src="https://host.ohiocashflow.com/sites/home-giveaway/videos/Productive-Morning.webm" type="video/webm">
          <source src="https://host.ohiocashflow.com/sites/home-giveaway/videos/Productive-Morning.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </respond-html>
      <div id="image-1" class="respond-image">          
        <img src="https://host.ohiocashflow.com:443/sites/home-giveaway/files/logo.png">
      </div>
      <p>Your purpose in life has to be bigger and better than yourself...&nbsp;<a href="#">DONATE</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container .jumbotron{
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 150px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 350px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.video-background { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a `z-index` to the parent, that creates a new stacking order starting at the parent. If you want a child element to be below it's parent, remove the parent `z-index` and use a negative `z-index` on the child.

```css
.container .jumbotron{
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 150px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 350px;
}

.video-background { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div id="block-1" class="block row jumbotron">
    <div class="col col-md-12">
      <respond-html id="html-5" description="HTML">                  
        <video class="video-background" autoplay="" loop="" poster="/static/template/themes/video-theme/video/video.jpg">
          <source src="https://host.ohiocashflow.com/sites/home-giveaway/videos/Productive-Morning.webm" type="video/webm">
          <source src="https://host.ohiocashflow.com/sites/home-giveaway/videos/Productive-Morning.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </respond-html>
      <div id="image-1" class="respond-image">          
        <img src="https://host.ohiocashflow.com:443/sites/home-giveaway/files/logo.png">
      </div>
      <p>Your purpose in life has to be bigger and better than yourself...&nbsp;<a href="#">DONATE</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```